# Why mysql max_allowed_packet reset to 1m automatically

Tags: mysql

I set

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16777216;
```

and also

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

I checked the max_allowed_packet through below command

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

and the value is = 16777216

But after some days max_allowed_packet automatically reset to 1M.

Answer (score 6):

i am pretty sure that your are hacked.  i had the same problem for months. i opened  general_log and finally found some codes:

```
   connect root@someipaddress on
   Query select 0x4D5A900..........(verylong)
   Query select sys_exe('cmd /c  c:/windows/nbvqc4.vbs')
   .........
   set global max_allowed_packet 1024
   ........
```

suggestion: change your root password.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has both GLOBAL variables and SESSION variables, as well as the my.cnf.

GLOBAL variables are initialised on startup from my.cnf, and many variables are taken from the GLOBAL value at connection time and copied into the SESSION.  If you change the GLOBAL value, the SESSION keeps it's own value -- but any new sessions will take the new GLOBAL default.

It seems that you did the right thing in terms of setting the GLOBAL variable and updating my.cnf, but in your example you ran "SHOW VARIABLES" which returns the SESSION value.  So it is possible you were not checking the correct value in that case.  I would recommend for all future checks that you check both the global and session values to help get an idea of what is changing when.

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';

For the value to change itself later, the following explanations are possible

(1) You are re-using a session that still has the old value
 (2) Another connection has run SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet, it is possible even that some uncourteous application or script is doing this
 (3) The server was restarted, and the my.cnf change is not being applied as expected -- perhaps the file is in the wrong path, or the setting exists more than once in the configuration file.  I would check the current Uptime in SHOW GLOBAL STATUS to understand if the server was restarted

I cannot think of any other reasons this would occur.  I did check to see if the client negotiates the server-side value when you pass --max_allowed_packet but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Mysql server is not restarted in my case.I set the max_allowed_packet and then close the connection.Then i again check the max_allowed_packet.And it set to 16777216.

Comment: That sounds very much like you are setting the session variable, and not the global variable.  Ensure you run SET GLOBAL and also check with SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES.  If you don't specify GLOBAL, it defaults to SESSION, which is lost once you close that session.

Comment: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet' = 16777216
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'= 16777216

Comment: Both the value are same for my case.My issue is that it automatically reset to 1M.
Mysql server not restarted.No other application execute the command 
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16777216;

Comment: I would suggest enabling the MySQL general query log (which logs all queries) so that you can search the log for SET next time this happens and determine if something is actually setting it for sure, because I cannot think of any other reason this would occur.

Comment: I enable the genernal log and find out that below query fired automatically.

370960 Query DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sys_exec 
150503 14:20:52 370960 Query DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS sys_eval 
370960 Query DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS cmdshell 
370960 Query set global log_bin_trust_function_creators=0 
370960 Query SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators=FALSE 
150503 14:20:53 370960 Query SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_routine_creators=0 
370960 Query SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1024 
370960 Query FLUSH PRIVILEGES

This is third-party udf library lib_mysqludf_sys.But i do not use.

Comment: Yes, you can see here that some application is issuing a global change to max_allowed_packet.  You need to track down that application and stop it from doing so.  It is not good behaviour for an application to run SET GLOBAL.  You could also consider removing the privilege of the user to change the variable, i.e. do not give them super user powers.

Comment: I don't have any application . How to track down that application?

Comment: There must be something connecting to the server.. it wouldn't execute that script on it's own.  My suggestion would be to look at the log to see what other queries are being run in the same connection for clues.. otherwise change the passwords and see what breaks and then give each application its own username so you can see what username is running this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, someone hack the system.I changed the root password and everything working fine.

Answer (score 0):

By default value of max_allowed_packet is 1M in MySQL. I believe size of your "max_allowed_packet" is exceed its upper limit. So, when you check "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';" its showing some negative value.

Additionally,

You have two values of max_allowed_packet in MySQL :

one on the client side : [mysql] section, [mysqldump], [client] and more.
one on the server side : [mysqld] section.

Comment: I edit my question .There is no negative in the 16777216 value .You interpreted as negative sign.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting 'Super' privilege of all users to 'N', except 1 admin user. This prevents users from changing max_allowed_packet.

Answer (score 0):

We just ran into this issue and the root cause is we were hacked. Some 3rd party was running a script that was changing the value down.

Tip for those trying to figure out if a hack is a root cause for them - temporarily change your MySQL logging to include all queries. That's how we ended up finding the issue.