# MySQL max_allowed_packet reset

Tags: mysql

For some reasons beyond my knowledge, I have to reset max_allowed_packet almost daily and sometimes multiple times during the day:

`SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;`

I have searched MySql bugs for a report along these lines but found nothing. I can not find any explanation as for why it is being reset to 1M.

Note the following:

1. The clients are mostly connected via J/Connector.
2. **`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`**

   ```
   "Uptime"
   "3028406" #this is almost 35 days
   ```
3. **`SELECT VERSION();`**

   ```
   "VERSION()"
   "5.6.22-log"
   ```
4. Operating System: Windows (Although I have a CentOS {mysql 5.6.30} server having the same issue but less often)

Comment: I do hope you get an answer, I have almost the exact problem only with the `table_open_cache` config

Comment: read some of the answers here too http://stackoverflow.com/q/28979660/

Answer (score 0):

Try to revoke the super privilegde:

```
REVOKE SUPER ON *.* FROM 'username'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Also you should try to change the root password.

Comment: Only root has SUPER privilege and no one has the root password. The worst thing is that this server is local in the company and we are the only technical guys here. No way someone else is doing this

Comment: @SherifelKhatib:- I am not sure but it can be the case that its hacked. (*Just a guess*) That is why I asked to change the root password and then try to check

Answer (score 0):

Change the setting in your `my.ini` or `~/.my.cnf`. This way the limit will also survive server restarts etc.

```
max_allowed_packet=1G
```

Your server has 35days uptime but maybe the mysql server has gone away in between.

Comment: In `my.ini`, I have included `max_allowed_packet=500M`