# Entity Framework with MySQL throws "Packets larger than max_allowed_packet are not allowed" unless I restart MySQL Server

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, mysql-error-1064

I'm using Entity Framework links to MySQL Server.
I'm sending a LINQ query with joins and selects, a complicated query.
I'm not inserting anything to DB.

However, I noticed this "Packets larger than max_allowed_packet are not allowed" throws once for a while.

I've already set "max_allowed_packet" to 1G!!

I found the only way to fix this issue is to restart the MySQL server. Once it is restarted, it fixes the problem. but I can't restart it each time.

1. It occurs randomly
2. When it occurs, wherever that using that Linq query will throw the exception. Run my test console program will also throw the error.
3. When it occurs, the LINQ query that returns the entire table still works fine. One table joins with another table works, but if I use groupby, it will throw exception.
4. I followed the MySQL manual to set the “max_allowed_packet” to 1G, but the exception still happens, every one or two days.
5. Restart MySQL Server will fix the problem for a while.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520029) might be related. Seems MySql loses the setting? Restarting fixes because the config setting is reapplied.

Comment: what could cause the setting get lost?

Comment: I'm facing similar issues at our end. May be @GordonLinoff can suggest us something on it?