# Why my intellij still keep the old error code

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

I'm trying to implement a idea about using Java and grabbing information from Mysql.
And after I run my main() in intellij
it shows up:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (4739923 > 1048576).
```

It seems that I need to change my "max-allowed-packet" setting.

So I search some solution like:
[Why mysql max_allowed_packet reset to 1m automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979660/why-mysql-max-allowed-packet-reset-to-1m-automatically?fbclid=IwAR1H7Bay5AkLOV11ddU7eJVUctTL3iknrS5Qc3oiaeZFkFQG3jH7mfUR00M)

And I really changed my "max_allowed_packet" variable by edit my my.cfg in server.

**But my intellij still came out same error message with same value.(4739923 > 1048576)**

Of course I had tried restart my Mysql and intellij.

any suggesttion will be helpful, thank u .

Comment: check SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'; what it shows

Comment: It shows the new value I edit it,but my intellij still remain the error code.

Comment: I remenber this discussion before, where the operating system also interferes, so not teh mysql is the bottelneck,it is something else

Comment: Okay I will keep trying,thank u too